# routing method when datatable and insert form are together

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I am trying to implement datatable in my form. I've a form and below that I've to show all the data present in the database. I am following the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwz_cMvASCo

I can not write the Route method for DataTable, the tutorial I was following teaches to display DataTable only, but here I have a form and below that display the DataTable. Please see the attached file.

```
// OrderedBookController controller class

use App\OrderedBook;
use Datatables;

public function index()
    {
        return view('pages.booksin');
    }

function fetchData()
{
    $ordered_books = OrderedBook::select('BookID', 'BilledNum','BilledDate', 'Qunatity', 'Price', 'Remarks');
    return Datatables::of($ordered_books)->make(true); //return an instance of the class or interface you request
}

//OrderedBook model class
class OrderedBook extends Model
{
    //
}
```

I do not know how to write route method to show the data.
My `web.php` class

```
Route::resource('/order','OrderedBookController');
```

My view page is inside `resources\views\pages\booksin.blade.php`

view page sample code

```
<table id="showBooksIn" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>BOOK ID</th>
                    <th>BILLED DATE</th>
                    <th>BILLED NUMBER</th>
                    <th>QUANTITY</th>
                    <th>PRICE</th>
                    <th>REMARKS</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#showBooksIn').DataTable({
            "processing":true,
            "serverside":true,
            "columns":[
                {"data": "BookID"},
                {"data": "BilledNum"},
                {"data": "BilledDate"},
                {"data": "Qunatity"},
                {"data": "Price"},
                {"data": "Remarks"},


            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
{
  return view('pages.booksin', $this->fetchData());
}
```

Try this.

Comment: what to write in javascript code for DataTable `"ajax":"{{route(' ')}}"`

Comment: Make a new route
Route::get('/order/data','OrderedBookController@fetchData')->name('data');
and then
"ajax":"{{route('data ')}}"